# WebView wrong Accept-Language headers when multiple languages selected

Tags: android, http-headers, android-webview

I have multiple languages selected in settings and when I access a website the Accept-Language headers that are being sent prioritize german over danish.

How does android assign a higher priority to german?

[image: sent accept language header]

[image]